# Moving files to a new directory not found in array

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops

Im looking for advice on the following. How can I implement where if a file exists other than what is being called for below ('02', '13' ect) be moved to an "ect" folder? For example.. All files under my source are correctly being sorted and moved to the corresponding destination folder, but if there happens to be a file named, "99", then I want it moved to the folder named, "Ect" under the destination root.

```
$srcRoot = "\\networkdrive source"
$dstRoot = "\\networkdrive dst"

# Map to destination subdirectory based on first 2 chars of file name
$map = @{
    '02' = '02 Folder'
    '13' = '13 Folder'
    '30' = '30 Folder'
    '33' = '33 Folder'
    '58' = '58 Folder'
    '82' = '82 Folder'
    '86' = '86 Folder'
}

$fileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $srcRoot -File -Force -Recurse
foreach ($file in $fileList)
{
    $key = $file.BaseName.Substring(1,2)
    if ($key -in $map.Keys)
    {
        $fileName = $file.Name
        $dstDir = Join-Path -Path $dstRoot -ChildPath $map[$key]
        # Create destination directory if needed
        if (-not (Test-Path -Path $dstDir))
        {
            #mkdir -Path $dstDir
        
        }
        Write-Verbose "Moving $($file.FullName)"
        if (Test-Path -Path (Join-Path -Path $dstDir -ChildPath $fileName))
        {
            # Error message if file already exists at destination
            Write-Error -Message "File $fileName already exists at $dstDir"
        } else {
            # OK to move file
            Move-Item -Path $($file.FullName) -Destination $dstDir
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically you're looking to implement what would be the `else` condition to your `if($key -in $map.Keys)`, right?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Yes, exactly.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$file.BaseName.Substring(0,2)`? (the first param is the zero-based index, the second param the length)

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to approach it, hope the inline comments helps to understand the logic, I would much rather use [`continue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-7.2#continue) whenever possible instead of `else`, though this is a personal preference and you mind as well change it if you wish to.

Worth noting, [*hash tables*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2) have a [`.ContainsKey(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.containskey?view=net-6.0#system-collections-hashtable-containskey(system-object)) method which you should always use instead of `$key -in $map.Keys`.

```
$srcRoot = "\\networkdrive source"
$dstRoot = "\\networkdrive dst"

$map = @{
    # map is defined here
}

foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Path $srcRoot -File -Force -Recurse) {
    $key = $file.BaseName.Substring(1,2)
    if ($map.ContainsKey($key)) {
        $fileName = $file.Name
        $dstDir = Join-Path -Path $dstRoot -ChildPath $map[$key]
        if (-not (Test-Path -Path $dstDir)) {
            # Create destination directory if needed
        }
        if (Test-Path -Path (Join-Path -Path $dstDir -ChildPath $fileName)) {
            # Error message if file already exists at destination
            Write-Error -Message "File $fileName already exists at $dstDir"
            # go next here
            continue
        }
        # OK to move file
        Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $dstDir
        # go next here
        continue
    }

    # this is else
    $dstDir = Join-Path -Path $dstRoot -ChildPath 'Ect'
    # should test if `Ect` folder exists ?
    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $dstDir)) {
        # Create destination directory if needed
    }
    if (Test-Path -Path (Join-Path -Path $dstDir -ChildPath $fileName)) {
        # throw error here and
        # go next after error
        continue
    }
    Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $dstDir
}
```

Comment: If I read the question, it should be `$key = $file.BaseName.Substring(0,2)`..

Comment: @Theo i saw your comment yesterday was waiting for OP to respond to it. Since he said it was working for the most part I didn't want to change it